# How to build dynamic where clause?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I have list of field names eg. `[:type, :car_id]` and changeset whereof
I want to get data from each field as scope.
How to build dynamic where clause with `and` between each expression created from list of fields, can I interpolate in where expression created earlier?

Not dynamic example:

```
def scoped_query(query, changeset, fields_names) do
  type_field = List.first(fields_names)
  car_id_field = List.last(fields_names)
  scope1 = get_field(changeset, type_field)
  scope2 = get_field(changeset, car_id_field)
  query |> where([m], field(m, ^type_field) == ^scope1 and field(m, ^car_id_field) == ^scope2)
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Enum.reduce/3](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Enum.html#reduce/3) with the initial query to build up the wheres:

```
Enum.reduce([:type, :car_id], query, fn field, acc ->
  value = get_field(changeset, field)
  where(acc, [m],field(m, ^field) == ^value)
end)
```

Answer (score 5):

Since you want to compare on `==` and join them with `and`, you can simply pass a keyword list to `where` making use of [Bindingless Queries](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.html) in Ecto 2.0+:

```
def scoped_query(query, changeset, fields_names) do
  criteria = for field <- fields_names, do: {field, get_field(changeset, field)}
  query |> where(^criteria)
end
```